# shell script for ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

can anybody tell me how can I create a shell script for ssh where I don't have to type the password manually?

I have learned expect command and I have tried multiple examples, but it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Please reply me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for whatever reason you need to rely only on expect, try something like (all one line):

`expect -c "spawn ssh <username>@a<address> <ssh commands/options> ; expect assword ; send $PASSWORD\n ; interact"`

Answer (score 8):

You could use `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id` to create a rsa key and add you key as allowed host for the remote computer.

Create a ssh key:
`$ ssh-keygen -t rsa`

Copy it to the remote computer as a allowed host:
`$ ssh-copy-id user@<IP/hostname>`
Eg
`$ ssh-copy-id username@12.345.67.890`

Comment: Huh.  I didn't know about the ssh-copy-id utility.  That makes life much nicer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [ssh agent](http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh) for providing the password only once during entire session, or use [key authentication with no password](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html).

Personally, I highly recommend you to not use such scripts where you either specify passwords on the command line, or by storing them in a text file. If your system will be compromised, you will definitely regret about that. Take in mind, that the first thing bad people looking into is your `.bash_history`.

Comment: hi, thank for reply. But do you know expect shell scrip, b'coz I have multiple scenario for giving password.

Comment: What multiple scenario? Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider not using a password at all and instead use a asymmetric key (e.g. RSA). It provides much better security and removes all the hassle of maintaining passwords...

Comment: ...and password protect your key as an extra layer of security. If you accidentally loose the media with your unprotected key on it, you're in danger.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your password into a shell script.  Shell scripts are not the place to put your password.  Putting your password into a shell script is inadvisable.  It is not recommended to put your password into a shell script.

If the above advice is not clear, repeat it a few dozen more times until it is.

With SSH your best bet is to use `ssh-keygen` to make a public/private key pair.  Then, on the remote machine, in `~/.ssh` (or wherever your SSH has been set up to look for its configuration) edit the file `authorized_keys` and paste your **PUBLIC** key.  The file will, afterwards, look something like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQ...elided for security...fdVEkAPINVd0=rsa-key-20100920
```

When that's in place you won't need a password to sign in.

---

*edited to add*

You need to place your **PRIVATE** key file into your local `~/.ssh` directory and make sure that only you can read it.

---

*further edited to add*

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051449/shell-script-for-ssh/5051483#5051483) mentions the `ssh-copy-id` utility which replaces all the manual editing I mentioned.  Nice touch that.  Use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

ssh-key:s is used for that, and basic usecase to add one looks like this:

```
ssh-keygen 
scp .ssh/id_rsa.pub user@server:.
ssh user@server "cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
ssh user@server "rm ~/id_rsa.pub"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a private/public key pair.

Then, write down your public key to the remote host you are going to ssh to this file:

```
 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

There are a lot of tutorials on how to do that. Just GOOGLE for: "ssh without password authorized_keys2".